# Swift: can't save array to UserDefaults

Tags: arrays, swift, save, nsuserdefaults

I have a class called `Stop`. This class implements `NSCoding`. I can save instances of `Stop` to UserDefaults with no problems. So far, so good. My problem is with saving an `Array` of stops. This is what I try:

```
private func save(stopArray array: [Stop],withKey key: String) {
        let data = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: array)
        self.userDefaults.set(data, forKey: key)
        self.userDefaults.synchronize()
    }

private func loadStopArray(key: String) -> [Stop]? {
        guard let data = self.userDefaults.object(forKey: key) as? Data else {
            return nil
        }
        return NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(with: data) as? [Stop]
}
```

Now, every time I call `loadStopArray` I get an empty array. Not nil, just an empty array.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: In order to judge what's happening, I think we'd need to see your implementation of Stop.

Comment: Are you sure that you are using the same exact key when saving and retrieving?

Comment: @matt you were right, my NSCoder constructor was returning nil... Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You are confusing loading `Object` and `Data`. `self.userDefaults.object()` to `self.userDefaults.data()` wil yield the data.

```
private func loadStopArray(key: String) -> [Stop]? {
        if let data = self.userDefaults.data(forKey: key) {
            return NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(with: data) as? [Stop]
        } else {
            return nil
        }
}
```